# returning confirmation message on same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I display a message on the same browser after inserting a student? Currently I am using return content which navigates me to a new page, but I want to display the message on same page and stay on the same page:

Index Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.ListAll().OrderByDescending(s => s.StudentID));

    }
```

Controller Action:

```
    public ActionResult RemoveStudent(int id)
    {

        StudentDataContext student= new StudentDataContext();

        var std = student.Students.Single(s => s.StudentID == id);
        student.Students.DeleteOnSubmit(std);
        student.SubmitChanges();
        return Content("Student " + std.StudentId.ToString() + " Removed");

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return your view, and you can store the message in a model or in your TempData.

```
public ActionResult RemoveStudent(int id)
{
    StudentDataContext student= new StudentDataContext();

    var std = student.Students.Single(s => s.StudentID == id);
    student.Students.DeleteOnSubmit(std);
    student.SubmitChanges();

    TempData["Message"] = "Student " + std.StudentId.ToString() + " Removed";
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In your view, you can check if `TempData["Message"]` is not null and display it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I have an index view where the remove action is triggered. It is this page where I want to display the message after executing RemoveStudent action

Comment: @user793468, then you can call RedirectToAction and pass in an Action/View and store the message in TempData, which will exist for a single request.

Answer (score 1):

You could return some specific view:

```
public ActionResult RemoveStudent(int id)
{
    StudentDataContext student= new StudentDataContext();
    var std = student.Students.Single(s => s.StudentID == id);
    student.Students.DeleteOnSubmit(std);
    student.SubmitChanges();

    ViewBag.Message = "Student " + std.StudentId.ToString() + " Removed";

    return View();

    // or if you want to specify a view name:
    // return View("MyView");

    // and if you need to pass a model that the view expects
    // return View("MyView", someModel);
}
```

and inside the view:

```
<div>@ViewBag.Message</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I have an index view where the remove action is triggered. It is this page where I want to display the message after executing RemoveStudent action

Answer (score 1):

You could do it asyncronously using AJAX. You can do this using JQuery:

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/

or an ajax form:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCPreview4UsingAjaxAndAjaxForm.aspx